# Publicly access NodeJS application running in IoT hub device

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have a NodeJS application using expressJS and socket.io. The NodeJS application running in a port 8080. I created this application as an IoT Edge solution and build and pushed to IoT device using docker from VS code. I need to access this NodeJS application publicly using IP and port or any other way (Not locally). How can I do this.

This NodeJS application sends data to another application using socket. So, a connection endpoint is needed. Please help.

Comment: Times like this paid ngrok won’t seem bad  https://ngrok.com/ comes in handy or you can set up a dynamic public Ip

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with a spring-boot application listening on 8080.

In my case, adding

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

in the Dockerfile fixed the issue.